# No output for If Like statement?

Tags: vb.net

So im trying to get this code to work but its not returning any values for the If Like portion
of the code.  I have no idea why this is happening.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    'display color button click event procedure should display the color of the item
    'whos item number is entered by the user.

    'all item numbers contain exactly seven characters
    'all items are available in four colors: blue, green, red, and white.
    'the fourth character in the item number indicates the items color
    'as follows: B or b indicates blue etc
    'if the item number does not contain 7 charactors OR
    'if the forth character is not one of the valid color characters,
    'the procedure should display the appropriate message

    If txtItem.Text Like "###[bBgGrRrwW]###" Then
        If txtItem.Text.Contains("bB") Then
            lblColor.Text = "Blue"
        ElseIf txtItem.Text.Contains("gG") Then
            lblColor.Text = "Green"
        ElseIf txtItem.Text.Contains("rR") Then
            lblColor.Text = "Red"
        ElseIf txtItem.Text.Contains("Ww") Then
            lblColor.Text = "White"
        End If
    ElseIf txtItem.Text IsNot "###[bBgGrRwW]###" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bad Job", "Color Project", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value in `txtItem.Text`?

Comment: Make sure you understand [what `Like` does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx), [what `IsNot` does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) and [what `Contains` does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).

Comment: the value of txtItem.Text is what the user enters into the text box.  I'm trying to validate the text with the like statement.  To the best of my knowledge this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have `.Contains("bB")`, you are asking it to check if the string contains `bB`, i.e. two characters. What you actually want to do is check if it contains `B` and ignore the case of the character. Although `Contains` does not have a case-insensitive option, `IndexOf` does: [String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you could use

```
If txtItem.Text.IndexOf("B", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
```

Comment: Or you could do `If txtItem.Text.ToLower.Contains("b") Then` I find it easier to read

Comment: @Pacane, that does not work in all situations (cultures), so using the overload of the `IndexOf` method is safer.  See the [Turkey Problem](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/) for more info.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Oh well, even the solution is provided in your link! `.ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`... haha this is insane though.

Comment: @Pacane You may like [Jon Skeet and Tony the Pony on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/7403673) for some more comments on globalisation issues.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That was awesome. But my favorite remains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result